What kind of pre-processing is used for image intensity values in YOLOv8?
Searching in GitHub and in the code I see contradictory statements. Does the normalization is just dividing the image intensity values (in range [0, 255]) by 255 (so it's in float range [0,1]) or it does normalization using z-score with some values (e.g. ImageNet mean and std as is suggested here)?
